# selenium script for mouse hovering using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mouseover

I am using Ruby on Rails to automate website. I am stuck on mouse hover and click action. I have to write code e.g. following website
http://www.sainsburys-live-well-for-less.co.uk/meal-planning/

I need to automate by hovering then clicking on Occasion > summer 
Following code i have written but it does not work

```
*menu = driver.find_element(:id => "Occasion")
submenu = driver.find_element(:id => "summer")
driver.action.move_to(menu).click(submenu).perform*
```

This code gives error "undefined local variable or method 'driver'".
please suggest.

Comment: 1. You have not posted the error message  2. Your title and introduction mention 'hovering', but your example and question are about 'clicking'. Which is it?

Comment: thanks for ur reply. First i need to hover over occasion then click on summer.error is "undefined local variable or method 'driver'

Comment: 1. Which line number is the error on?  2. Please post your code that loads the webdriver. 3. Which selenium functions work for you? (How far did you get before you got stuck?)

Comment: Thank you such.. I have used click_when_clickable() function and it works.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please post the solution. If not, please identify the line with the error, and post code for a minimum working example of your problem.